# How to make a method that checks if there is an odd number in an array?

Tags: java

Im trying to make a method which checks if there is an odd number in an array. If there is an odd number it should return true. If there are no odd numbers in the array it should return false. For example if the array a is {1,2,3} it should return true because there is an odd number.

Here is the array:

```
int[] arraySum1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

The problem is the boolean variable hasUneven is reset everytime it goes into the for loop. In this case it only checks the last value which is 10 in this case and then return false everytime I call the method.

Here is my code so far:

```
public boolean hasUneven(int[] a) {
    boolean hasUneven = false;
    int uneven = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        uneven = a[i];

        if (uneven % 2 != 0) {
            hasUneven = true;
        } else {
            hasUneven = false;
        }
    }

    return hasUneven;
}
```

Comment: Execute your code step by step with a debugger, or on a piece of paper, writing the successive values of the variables, and you will understand.

Comment: Just remove the `else` branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill array with odd numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184782/fill-array-with-odd-numbers)

Comment: Stream version: `Arrays.stream(arraySum1).anyMatch(i -> i % 2 == 1)`

Comment: @tarek I don't see why this would be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directy return when you find your first odd number.

```
public boolean hasUneven(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] % 2 != 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an exit condition. You can do that by returning `true` as soon as there is an uneven number e.g.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        uneven = a[i];
        if (uneven % 2 != 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
 return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your method should return *as soon* as it has found an odd number. Now your code traverses the entire array and assigns the `hasUneven` value for *each number*. 10 being the last one and therefore an even number.

Try replacing your `if` construction with:

```
if (uneven % 2 != 0) {
   return true;
}

...
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
if(a[i]/2=0)
return true;
}else{
return false }
```

Comment: This code is not explained, does not fix the OP's problem, and does not even compile.